# #define macro does not take variable values

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have created `#define` statement in project's `pch` file so it can be seen in all files in the project, the statement is: `#define MYURL(x,y) @"http://internal-sps/providers.aspx?category=(a)&regionID=(y)"`

however, I use this macro in any file inside the project like this:

`NSString *url = MYURL(@"category1",@"3")`;

then `NSLog(@"%@", url);` the console shows this:

`http://internal-sps/providers.aspx?category=(a)&regionID=(y)` not the actual values.

how can i get the actual values for this macro ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

`#define MYURL(x,y) @"http://internal-sps/providers.aspx?category=(a)&regionID=(y)"`

to:

`#define MYURL(x,y) "http://internal-sps/providers.aspx?category=(a)&regionID=("y")"`

and use your macro like this:

`NSString *url = @MYURL("category1","3");`

---

Note: if that `a` is actually meant to be an `x` then it would be:

`#define MYURL(x,y) "http://internal-sps/providers.aspx?category=("x")&regionID=("y")"`

Comment: You should also leave off the `@` when calling the macro, I believe.

Comment: Actually, shouldn't you leave off the `#` marks in the define string? He's calling the macro with quoted strings.

Comment: Paul when I call this macro like this: NSString *cat = @"category1"; MYURL(cat,@"1"); and then NSLog it, the consol will show the word "cat" in the url not its actual value, how can i get it to pass the actual value of cat that is defined just before the macro call ?

Comment: using the symbol @ before the macro call produces a syntax error, and I want to know how to use a variable in the call like this: NSString *cat = @"category1"; MYURL(cat,@"1");

Comment: @JAHelia: if you want to use variables as well as literals then you will need to use a function rather than a macro (macros are generally a bad idea for this kind of thing anyway)

Comment: @Paul but i saw a lot of projects out there that use the macro as a function (or a small function), however, using the @ symbol produces this syntax error: unexpected '@' in the program.

Comment: @JAHelia: just because other people abuse the preprocessor and write macros instead of functions that doesn't mean that it's a good thing to do - in general you should always prefer functions - they are more robust and easier to debug - macros should only ever be a last resort when there are extenuating circumstances

Comment: Agreed, a static inline function is nearly always preferable for something like this.